# Imap Error connection error with the server

Tags: imap, dovecot

I have no idea why I can't login to rondcube. Thats logs.

[26-Jul-2018 11:50:13 +0000]:  IMAP Error: Login failed for test from 155.133.37.159. Could not connect to localhost:143: Connection refused in /var/www/himeljob/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 196 (POST /webmail/?_task=login&_action=login)
[26-Jul-2018 12:03:00 +0000]:  IMAP Error: Login failed for test from 155.133.37.159. Could not connect to localhost:143: Connection refused in /var/www/himeljob/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 196 (POST /webmail/?_task=login&_action=login)
[26-Jul-2018 12:03:03 +0000]:  IMAP Error: Login failed for test from 155.133.37.159. Could not connect to localhost:143: Connection refused in /var/www/himeljob/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 196 (POST /webmail/?_task=login&_action=login)

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your server is running? Connection refused means no application is listening on the port, so or your server isn't running or you have the wrong port.

Comment: [26-Jul-2018 12:30:57 +0000]: <t46aov60> IMAP Error: Login failed for test2@himeljob.pl from 155.133.37.159. AUTHENTICATE PLAIN: Authentication failed. in /var/www/himeljob/webmail/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 196 (POST /webmail/?_task=login&_action=login)

Comment: After full reinstal my dovecot listen to port 143 when I login himeljob.pl to telnet

Comment: And I get error with Plain login

Comment: hi i am now working on roundcube i also had the same problem. i reinstalled the os. and tried then also did not work. roundcube opened when i again installed dovecot-core dovecot-imapd. but again now not able to open inbox i get error mailbox not selectable